# Bind UIImageView in NIB to Element of NSMutableArray of UIImageViews

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `IBOutlet UIImageView` elements and I want to bind each individual element of the array to a separate `UIImageView` defined in my NIB file.  While I can bind it to other solitary `IBOutlet UIImageView` objects, the Interface Builder does not even give me an option to bind to the array or an element of it.  I am building a tic tac toe game and want to combine the 9 individual `UIImageView` "squares" that I have into one array representing the whole board so that I can more elegantly reference the board in code.

Is this even possible?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using iOS 3.0 (as your question's tag implies), I don't think you can do it in your nib.

If you are using iOS 4.0 or later, you can do it in your nib.  Here's how.

You need to set up your `NSMutableArray` as an `IBOutletCollection`, like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSMutableArray *imageViews;

@end
```

Then you can control-drag from your `ViewController` (probably the File's Owner) to each image view and add it to the `imageViews` collection.

Comment: Rob, looks like that is the case!  What an oversight in the earlier versions of the SDK!  I was able to get 90% of the way there by adding the individual `IBOutlet UIImageView` objects to an array after initializing them so that I was able to manipulate them in code as I wanted, but I still had to keep the declarations around for Interface Builder.  Since that isn't 100% what I was looking for as it can't be done in iOS 3, I am accepting your answer.  Thanks!